# Syntax error at end of input in PostgreSQL Transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I'm trying to execute this transaction but the error "error at end of input" makes little sense to me. Would appreciate anyone giving advice thank you:

```
DO $$
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO FlightBooking VALUES(10006, 20006, 30001, 4, 'r', '01/02/2021 22:55:44', 799.96);

  SELECT CustomerID FROM LeadCustomer WHERE CustomerID = 20006; 
  ROLLBACK;

  UPDATE FlightBooking SET NumSeats = NumSeats + 1, TotalCost = TotalCost + 100
  WHERE CustomerID = 20006;
  ROLLBACK;

  IF ((SELECT Available_Seats FROM SeatInformation(30001) WHERE Status = 'r') < 1) THEN 
  ROLLBACK;

COMMIT;
$$
```

Comment: The commit and rollbacks make no sense to me. What are you trying to do with that? You could reduce the whole script to just the last `IF` statement. The insert and update are undone by the corresponding rollbacks.

Comment: I'm trying to execute the sequence of statements only if they all succeed, I guess the rollbacks are unnecessary for this?

Comment: The rollbacks will immediately undo the INSERT or UPDATE so there will be nothing to commit at the end.

Comment: You cannot have a `ROLLBACK` in a PL/pgSQL `DO` statement. There is no destination for the `SELECT`. This syntax is so far removed from anything sensible that I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is what I've been asked to do: "Enter flight booking as requested, including total cost for the booking. The
entering of a new booking should work as an atomic operation so either the
whole booking (insert of lead customer if required, insert of flight booking
itself) succeeds or it fails. Hence lead customers should not be added if the
flight booking does not get added. If any problems occur during the booking
(e.g. the seats are not available or any of the insert fails) the booking should
be cancelled and all of the operations undone"

Answer (score 0):

`if` requires an `end if`

```
IF ((SELECT Available_Seats FROM SeatInformation(30001) WHERE Status = 'r') < 1) THEN 
   ROLLBACK;
END IF;
```

Comment: Sorry about the silly mistake. However, the same error occurs.

Comment: @Rubbs: which tool do you use to run that? Maybe it doesn't understand the dollar quoting.

Comment: It was the "commit" it didn't understand, changed it to "end". But now saying missing FROM-clause entry for table "flightbooking". Changed the IF ... THEN ROLLBACK to IF ... THEN delete from flightbooking where customerid = x;